# Gmail email id validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation, email, gmail

if every one has noticed Gmail provides a wide range of email address probability.

so if ur email id is `example@gmail.com`

it can be used as

```
e.xample@gmail.com
e.x.ample@gmail.com
exa.mple@gmail.com
e.xam.ple@gmail.com
e.x.ample@gmail.com
e.xa.m.ple@gmail.com
...
```

and all this can be used as your official email id and mails to it will be sent in your `example@gmail.com`. The basic hampering of this is for registration modules leading to spamy registration.

my question was is there any way i can have a validation for this.

sorry if this question sounds lengthy and thanks in advance

Comment: Is this client side (JavaScript) validation, server side (PHP) validation, or both?

Comment: @VishalSuthar i tried RE but it did not work out well, i tried looping '.' but couldnot design the proper RE for it

Comment: Just removing `.` and anything after `+` should do the job surely?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
```

<kbd>[Regex Demo](http://regexr.com?37091)</kbd>